# Win PowerShell Script Stopped Running

Tags: powershell

Up until the end of last month 8/31/2022, I have had a functioning PS script that pings a server and sends an email with either 'All is well' or 'Problem!'. At or around 8/31 or 9/1, the emails stopped being sent, so I've begun to investigate. I have Win Task Scheduler for automating and its history shows that the bat file is being process/run as expected.

However, when I try to run the PowerShell script on its own as admin, I first received the error of:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy : Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy successfully, but the setting is overridden by a policy defined at a more specific scope.
```

Here was my initial Get-ExecutionPolicy -List:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-ExecutionPolicy -List

        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy    RemoteSigned
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser       Undefined
 LocalMachine    RemoteSigned
```

So I tried setting the ExecutionPolicy, via cmd line and regedit and gpedit.

When I ran **Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass** in PS, I get the following error:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy : Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy successfully, but the setting is overridden by a policy defined at a more specific scope.  Due to the override, your shell will retain its current effective execution policy of RemoteSigned. Type "Get-ExecutionPolicy -List" to view your execution policy settings. For more information please see "Get-Help Set-ExecutionPolicy".
At line:1 char:46
+ ...  -ne 'AllSigned') { Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process Bypass }; & 'C ...
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy], SecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionPolicyOverride,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPolicyCommand
```

Then I run Get-ExecutionPolicy -List:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-ExecutionPolicy -List

        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy    RemoteSigned
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser       Undefined
 LocalMachine    ByPass
```

And when I try to run the script now, PowerShell opens up, but hangs forever without running the script. This used to work, I don't know what has happened to make it not work.

There are many sites with different opinions of what needs to happen around the ExecutionPolicy.
What do I need to do in order for this to work again? What are the definitive requirements? Honestly, I'd rather not use PowerShell as it always seems to have these 'permission' issues.

This may also be an issue:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online

but the article does not seem to provide a definitive 'fix'.

Many Thanks for any help!

**UPDATED**

thanks @mklement0, so I ran your Set... and my ExecutionPolicy is now as seen below. Is this correct?

```
Scope ExecutionPolicy
----- ---------------
MachinePolicy    Bypass
UserPolicy       Undefined
Process          Bypass
CurrentUser      Undefined
LocalMachine     RemoteSigned
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the error message is trying to tell is that while the execution policy was set for the *requested scope*, one set in a scope *with higher precedence* overrides it.

You have a GPO-based `MachinePolicy` set, which overrides all other scopes,
and makes any attempts to call [`Set-ExecutionPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy) or the PowerShell CLI's `-ExecutionPolicy` parameter ineffective: all code on your machine will run with policy `RemoteSigned` in effect.

To allow `Set-ExecutionPolicy` / `-ExecutionPolicy` to control the effective execution policy, no policy must be set in either GPO-based scope (that is, [`Get-ExecutionPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-executionpolicy) `-List` should show `Undefined` for both  the `MachinePolicy` and `UserPolicy` scopes).

---

*Without* a GPO-based policy in effect, when PowerShell is called *from the outside*, such as from Task Scheduler, the execution policy is usually bypassed on a *per-process-only* basis, via the PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)'s `-ExecutionPolicy` parameter, e.g.:

```
powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File someScript.ps1
```

That is, `-ExecutionPolicy ByPass` on the command line is the equivalent of calling `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Force` from inside a PowerShell session.

See also:

- The conceptual [about_Execution_Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies) help topic.

Comment: thanks @mklement0, I've updated my question to show I've updated my ExecutionPolicy. I its current status what you would expect?

Comment: @Redink: I'd set the `MachinePolicy`  to `Undefined`, which will make the `LocalMachine` policy take effect (`RemoteSigned`, which is a good compromise: run local scripts, but prevent running scripts downloaded from the web). Once that  is in effect, you no longer need `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` in your CLI calls (but it doesn't hurt). `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` is primarily useful if you know the script to be safe but want to guard against the effective execution policy being `Restricted` (default on client Windows editions) or `AllSigned`. However, as stated, it cannot override GPO policies.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm still a bit foggy here, my current standing for the 5 are as follows: MachinePolicy=Restricted, UserPolicy=Undefined, Process=Undefined, CurrentUser=Undefined, LocalMachine=RemoteSigned. Is this what you would recomment? And it sounds like I should add **-ExecutionPolicy ByPass** CLI, where and how do i do that? Then it also sounds like even if all of these things work, I may still have issues based on the Exchange Server Authentication Update, see link above.

Comment: @Redink: If you set the `MachinePolicy` to `Restricted`, you won't be able to execute _any_ scripts - set it to `Undefined` instead, and set the `LocalMachine` scope to `RemoteSigned`. Then - on that machine - you don't need `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` in CLI calls (unless you're trying to use downloaded-fron-the-web scripts as-is, which is ill-advised). If you do need to use `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass`  (on machines where you don't know the effective policy), use it like in the sample CLI call shown in the answer.

Comment: @Redink: Connecting to Exchange Online is unrelated to local script-execution policies.